# KeyNotFoundException in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I got an Exception here that doesn't find the `rootPartNo`  key in  `unbreakableLinkMap`  dictionary.

```
MyTree<IDbRecord> currentTree = PartHelper.GetTreeForRootId(succesorId, graph);
#region TreeSheet
string rootPartNo = currentTree.Root.Payload.GetField(Part.c_partNo).GetString();

//get spirit links
var spiritLinks = graph.unbreakableLinkMap[rootPartNo];
Worksheet treeWS = excel.Worksheets[2];
treeWS.Name = "Tree";
long displayedPartId = long.Parse(GetIdFromSession(Part.t_name));
int rowNo = 0;
bool bold = false;
Color color = Color.Black;
foreach (MyTreeNode<IDbRecord> node in currentTree.Root.DepthFirstNodeEnumerator)
{
    string partNo = node.Payload.GetField(Part.c_partNo).GetString();
    treeWS.Cells[rowNo, node.Depth].PutValue(partNo);
    bold = false;
    color = Color.Black;
    if (spiritLinks.Find(suc => suc.PartNo == partNo || suc.SucPartNo == partNo) != null)
    {
        color = Color.Red;
    }
    if (node.Payload.GetField(Part.c_id).GetInt64() == displayedPartId)
    {
        bold = true;
    }

    headerFStyle.Font.IsBold = bold;
    headerFStyle.Font.Color = color;
    treeWS.Cells[rowNo, node.Depth].SetStyle(headerFStyle);
    rowNo++;
}
```

How can I check/validate this?

Comment: Did you use a debugger?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't show much, just that the dictionary does not have values.

Comment: Check/validate what? If the dictionary says the key is not in there, it's not. You don't need to check/validate that. What's probably going on is that either the key is in a different case (a dictionary is, by default, `case-sensitive`). You can also use the `Contains()` or `TryGet()` method(s) to avoid the exception and first check if the value is in it.

Comment: It seems, that you have either wrong `rootPartNo` value or dictionary. Could you provide `rootPartNo;` value as well as dictionary's keys: `String.Join(", ", graph.unbreakableLinkMap.Keys);`?

Comment: if the dictionary doesnt have values... that says a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually you get this exception when the key specified for accessing an element in a collection does *not* match any key in the collection.

I would suggest use the debugger and see you have that `Key` available in the `Dictionary`

If you are unsure of key existence, I would suggest writing defensive code, using  `ContainsKey` or `TryGetValue`.

```
if (graph.unbreakableLinkMap.ContainsKey(key)) 
{
     ... 
}
```

or

```
if (graph.unbreakableLinkMap.TryGetValue(key, out spiritLinks)) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to debug. Put a breakpoint on the

```
  var spiritLinks = graph.unbreakableLinkMap[rootPartNo];
```

line, run the routine and inspect the values of question:

```
  rootPartNo
```

as well as dictionary keys

```
  graph.unbreakableLinkMap.Keys
```

If you can't use debugger for whatever reason, add debug output

```
  ...
  string rootPartNo = currentTree.Root.Payload.GetField(Part.c_partNo).GetString();

  // Debug output: when key is not found, show additional info
  if (!graph.unbreakableLinkMap.ContainsKey[rootPartNo])
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format(
      "Key to find is \"{0}\" and keys in the dictionary are\r\n{1}", 
      rootPartNo, 
      String.Join(", ", graph.unbreakableLinkMap.Keys)));

  ...
```